# CASE statement not working with "NOT LIKE" condition in T-SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, coalesce

What's wrong with this syntax?  And how can I fix it?

**Here is the error:**

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnTestResultStringNEW, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnTestResultStringNEW, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

**Here is the T-SQL code:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTestResultStringNEW]
(
    @testId INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(512)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @totalString NVARCHAR(512)  
    SET @totalString = ''
    SELECT @totalString = 
        COALESCE(       
            CASE substance.sortorder NOT LIKE '%.0' THEN
                CASE WHEN @totalString = '' THEN
                    testresult.result 
                ELSE
                    @totalString + ', ' + testresult.result             
                END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN @totalString = '' THEN
                    testresult.result 
                ELSE
                    @totalString            
                END
            END     
        , '')
    FROM [dbo].[testresult_audit] AS testresult
    JOIN [dbo].[test_testresult] 
        ON  testresult.testresultid = test_testresult.testresultid 
            AND testresult.versionnumber = test_testresult.testresultversionnumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN substance ON substance.substanceid = testresult.substanceid
    WHERE 
    test_testresult.testid = @testid
    ORDER BY substance.sortorder, testresult.result

    RETURN @totalString
END
```

**This works:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTestResultStringNEW]
(
    @testId INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(512)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @totalString NVARCHAR(512)  
    SET @totalString = ''
    SELECT @totalString = 
        COALESCE(       
            --CASE substance.sortorder NOT LIKE '%.0' THEN
                CASE WHEN @totalString = '' THEN
                    testresult.result 
                ELSE
                    @totalString + ', ' + testresult.result             
                END
            --ELSE
            --  CASE WHEN @totalString = '' THEN
            --      testresult.result 
            --  ELSE
            --      @totalString            
            --  END
            --END       
        , '')
    FROM [dbo].[testresult_audit] AS testresult
    JOIN [dbo].[test_testresult] 
        ON  testresult.testresultid = test_testresult.testresultid 
            AND testresult.versionnumber = test_testresult.testresultversionnumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN substance ON substance.substanceid = testresult.substanceid
    WHERE 
    test_testresult.testid = @testid
    ORDER BY substance.sortorder, testresult.result

    RETURN @totalString
END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the `WHEN`:

```
CASE substance.sortorder NOT LIKE '%.0' THEN
```

Change to:

```
CASE WHEN substance.sortorder NOT LIKE '%.0' THEN
```